# Storyboard tab bar controller view orientation landscape/portrait

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, storyboard, landscape-portrait

I want my tab bar application with three tabs in landscape mode, but the third tab must be in portrait. I ended up converting the whole app to landscape using

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

in every view controllers as tab bar application requires all its sub view controllers to be in landscape for this.

My .plist file have Landscape option first and then added portrait.

How can I make third tab to rotate to portrait?

Answer (score 2):

The UITabBarController, sadly, doesn't handle view controllers with different rotation requirements very well. The best way to handle this is to subclass UITabBarController and in shouldAutorotate, simply pass the request on to the view controller that is on screen. The code would look like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Let's grab an array of all of the child view controllers of this tab bar controller
NSArray *childVCArray = self.viewControllers;

// We know that at 5 or more tabs, we get a "More" tab for free, which contains, assumingly,
// a more navigation controller

if (self.selectedIndex <= 3) {
    UINavigationController *navController = [childVCArray objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];

    // We're in one of the first four tabs, which we know have a top view controller of UIViewController
    UIViewController *viewController = navController.topViewController;

    return [viewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}
else {
    // This will give us a More Navigation Controller

    UIViewController *viewController = [childVCArray objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];

    return [viewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

return NO;
}
```

This assumes that you're 5+ view controllers use the tab bar's more navigation controller and are not themselves in their own uinavigationcontroller. If they were, altering this code to fit would be trivial.

I have posted this subclass up on my github, so you can copy this method or just grab the .h/.m files from [here](https://github.com/jmstone617/PickyTabBarController)

Comment: I added your files for tabbarcontroller .Edited it for three tabs.
    if (self.selectedIndex <= 2)  and removed the else case for "more".
In third view controller as I want only that to be in portrait ,return YES for (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); in should autorotate method .
But still its not rotating to prtrait.Where am I wrong?

Comment: selectedIndex starts at 0, so if you have 3 tabs thats 0, 1, and 2. Are the view controllers inside UINavigationControllers? If you look at the code, it is assuming the view controller of the tab bar is a nav controller, and it grabs the top view controller of that. If you just have view controllers, nix the nav controller stuff

Comment: Thanks for reply jmstone..
The third view is not in a navigation controller .So I just added UIViewController *viewController = [childVCArray objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];  
 for selectedIndex==2
Now the view rotates to portrait when I change the device orientation to portrait.But then all other tabs become portrait .

I want the third view to be forced to portrait whenever selected(not only when device is changing its orientation).And the other tabs must always remain in landscape.Any suggestion?